# SpringBoot with Keycloak as Service provider using SAML protocol and Microsoft as Identity Provider

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak, saml-2.0

Can anyone help me out with my problem.
Scenario - I am trying to configure a SpringBoot application that will redirect to Keycloak client which is using SAML protocol, which will again redirect to Azure as Identity Provider(IDP) .

I tried lots of pom.xml, application.properties configuration regarding keycloak in springboot, also tried to override the filter classess but none of them worked for me.